# delete a movieclip forever

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

im just trying to delete forever a mc.
i create a mc and then i make an addChild of a sprite.

```
var mcSwap1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mcSwap1);
mcSwap1.addChild(mySprite);
```

if i want to delete from everywhere and forever mcSwap1, what can i do?

```
removeChild(mcSwap1);
mcSwap1=null;
```

doesn't work very well...the memory is not really free!

thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing there is the best you can do, remember you could maybe remove mySprite from mcSwap1 too. Also remember to remove any event listeners etc